# Ruby String pad zero OPE ID

Tags: ruby, string, printf, zero-pad

I'm working with OPE IDs. One file has them with two trailing zeros, eg, `[998700, 1001900]`. The other file has them with one or two leading zeros for a total length of six, eg, `[009987, 010019]`. I want to convert every OPE ID (in both files) to an eight-digit string with exactly two leading zeros and however many zeros at the end to get it to be eight digits long.

Comment: Do you want all of them to have 2 leading zeroes or just ones that already have them?

Comment: Best would be if you showed what result you'd like to get.

Comment: @detunized, all of them. Thank you. I edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = [ "00123123", "077934", "93422", "1231234", "12333" ]
a.map { |n| n.gsub(/^0*/, '00').ljust(8, '0') }

=> ["00123123", "00779340", "00934220", "001231234", "00123330"]
```

Comment: I like the `ljust` usage here

Answer (score 1):

If you have your data parsed and stored as strings, it could be done like this, for example.

```
n = ["998700", "1001900", "009987", "0010019"]
puts n.map { |i|
    i =~ /^0*([0-9]+?)0*$/
    "00" + $1 + "0" * [0, 6 - $1.length].max
}
```

Output:

```
00998700
00100190
00998700
00100190
```

This example on [codepad](http://codepad.org/ZFpqaY6T).

I'm note very sure though, that I got the description exactly right.  Please check the comments and I correct in case it's not exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the answers given by @detunized & @nimblegorilla, I came up with:

`"998700"[0..-3].rjust(6, '0').to_sym`

to make the first format I described (always with two trailing zeros) equal to the second.

Comment: you have a typo, get rid of `.` after your number string